# c# backgroundworker interrupted by .Net task?

Tags: c#, performance, backgroundworker

I have a Backgroundworker to collect data from a UPD device. I need to fetch data from te device every 35 ms else it wil be overwriten. The problem is that I every +/- 5 seconds I missed some data. If I look at the timestamps generated in the Trace, I see that the delay was outside the backgroundworker thread. 
I allready increased the performance by flushing the Trace log and the two text writer objects when I want it.

Does anyone has a idea what the cause of the delay is?

Here is my code:

```
public DataCaptureTabViewModel()
{
  SelectDirectoryCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSelectDirectoryCommand);
  OpenDirectoryCommand= new RelayCommand(OnOpenDirectoryCommand);
  StartStopCaptureCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStartStopCaptureCommand);

  var cmdAppl = new GetApplicationSettings();
  Mediator.Default.Raise(cmdAppl);
  var applicationSettings = cmdAppl.AppSettings;

  FilePath = applicationSettings.DefaultPath;

  EnableControls = false;

  _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
  {
    WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
    WorkerReportsProgress = true
  };
  _backgroundWorker.DoWork += CaptureThread_DoWork;
  _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += CaptureThread_ProgressChanged;
}


private void CaptureThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  var bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
  if (bgw == null) throw new ArgumentException("UpdateBackgroundWorker_DoWork: wrong arguments!");
  bgw.ReportProgress(-1, new StringEventArgs(string.Format("Horizontal: {0}/{1}   Vertical: {2}/{3} [dropped lines/total]", 0, 0, 0, 0)));

  var lastCaptureTime = DateTime.Now;
  var lastStatusUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
  var scannedLinesW = 0;
  var scannedLinesH = 0;
  var droppedLinesW = 0;
  var droppedLinesH = 0;
  const int nrOfLinesToFlushFileAfter = 500;
  uint lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW = 1;
  uint lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH = 1;
  var firstTimeStampW = true;
  var firstTimeStampH = true;
  TextWriter twW = new StreamWriter(_completeFilePadW, true);
  TextWriter twH = new StreamWriter(_completeFilePadH, true);
  const string header = "Timestamp; Position;";
  var headerW = header;
  for (var i = 0; i < NrOfHorizontalBits; i++)
  {
    headerW += string.Format("b{0};", i);
  }
  var headerH = header;
  for (var i = 0; i < NrOfVerticalBits; i++)
  {
    headerH += string.Format("b{0};", i);
  }
  twW.WriteLine(headerW);
  twH.WriteLine(headerH);
  //send cmd to clear overflow counters and make all buffers invalid
  SelectedEmbeddedController.ResetBeamBuffers();
  //retrieve sampleTime
  var sampleTime = RetrieveSampleTime();
  if (sampleTime == 0) sampleTime = 1;
  var flushFilesAfterInMs = sampleTime * nrOfLinesToFlushFileAfter;
  var lastFlushedTimeW = DateTime.Now;
  var lastFlushedTimeH = lastFlushedTimeW.AddMilliseconds((int)(flushFilesAfterInMs / 3));
  var lastFlushedTraceBuffer = lastFlushedTimeW.AddMilliseconds((int)(flushFilesAfterInMs / 3) * 2);
  while (!bgw.CancellationPending)
  {
    //wait, flush in this wait time if needed
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    if (Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(now, lastFlushedTimeW) > flushFilesAfterInMs)
    {
      lastFlushedTimeW = DateTime.Now;
      twW.Flush();
    }
    if (Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(now, lastFlushedTimeH) > flushFilesAfterInMs)
    {
      lastFlushedTimeH = DateTime.Now;
      twH.Flush();
    }
    if (Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(now, lastFlushedTraceBuffer) > flushFilesAfterInMs)
    {
      lastFlushedTraceBuffer = DateTime.Now;
      Trace.Flush();
    }
    var delay = (int)(MinCaptureTimeInMs - Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(DateTime.Now, lastCaptureTime));
    if (delay > 0)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
    //end wait

    // capturing data
    var startFetch = DateTime.Now;
    DebugLogging.WriteLine("*** Fetch all buffers");
    const int nrOfRegistersW = (NrOfBuffersUsed * NrOfRegistersPerBufferW);
    const int nrOfRegistersH = (NrOfBuffersUsed * NrOfRegistersPerBufferH);
    var registersImageW = RetrieveCompleteRegisterBlock(FirstScanRegisterW, nrOfRegistersW);
    var registersImageH = RetrieveCompleteRegisterBlock(FirstScanRegisterH, nrOfRegistersH);
    DebugLogging.WriteLine("*** Fetch all buffers, ready, FetchTime={0}; timeDiff={1} ms", Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(DateTime.Now, startFetch), Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(DateTime.Now, lastCaptureTime));
    lastCaptureTime = DateTime.Now;

    /* process Width data */
    if (registersImageW == null)
    {
      DebugLogging.WriteLine("Warning: Width, failed to fetch!");
    }
    else
    {
      //first store the received register data into DataStructure List
      var dataStructureListW = new List<DataStructure>();
      for (var i = 0; i < NrOfBuffersUsed; i++)
      {
        dataStructureListW.Add(RetrieveDataBuffer(registersImageW, (NrOfRegistersPerBufferW * i), NrOfHorizontalBits));
      }

      //delete zerro and older datasets
      dataStructureListW.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs == 0 || x.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW);

      //order list by timestamp
      var sortedDataStructureListW = dataStructureListW.OrderBy(o => o.TimeStampInMs).ToList();

      ////delete zerro datasets
      //sortedDataStructureListW.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs == 0);

      ////delete older datasets
      //sortedDataStructureListW.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW);

      // parse all horizontal data
      var nrOfLinesProcessed = 0;
      foreach (var datastructure in sortedDataStructureListW)
      {
        ////first check if timestamp is newer than the last processed buffer
        //if (datastructure.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW)
        //{
        //  DebugLogging.WriteLine("Width: Skip buffer, timestamp {0} is same or older then last processed buffer {1}", datastructure.TimeStampInMs, lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW);
        //  continue;
        //}

        int nrOfLinesDiff;
        if (firstTimeStampW)
        {
          nrOfLinesDiff = 1;
          firstTimeStampW = false;
        }
        else
        {
          nrOfLinesDiff = (int)((datastructure.TimeStampInMs - lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW) / sampleTime);//how many samples between last fetch and this
          var remainder = (datastructure.TimeStampInMs - lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW) % sampleTime;
          if (remainder == (sampleTime - 1))
          {
            nrOfLinesDiff++;
          }
        }
        if (nrOfLinesDiff > 1)
        {
          DebugLogging.WriteLine("Width: ## Missed {0} Lines", nrOfLinesDiff - 1);
          droppedLinesW += nrOfLinesDiff - 1;
        }

        //process data
        lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampW = datastructure.TimeStampInMs;
        //DebugLogging.WriteLine("--- Width: Process buffer with timestamp {0}", datastructure.TimeStampInMs);
        //store this data
        twW.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2};", datastructure.TimeStampInMs, datastructure.PositionInMs, datastructure.GetDataString());
        scannedLinesW++;
        nrOfLinesProcessed++;
      }
      DebugLogging.WriteLine("Width: Processed {0} Lines", nrOfLinesProcessed);
    }

    /* process Height data */
    if (registersImageH == null)
    {
      DebugLogging.WriteLine("Warning: Height, failed to fetch!");
    }
    else
    {
      //first store the received register data into DataStructure List
      var dataStructureListH = new List<DataStructure>();
      for (var i = 0; i < NrOfBuffersUsed; i++)
      {
        dataStructureListH.Add(RetrieveDataBuffer(registersImageH, (NrOfRegistersPerBufferH * i), NrOfVerticalBits));
      }

      //delete zerro and older datasets
      dataStructureListH.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs == 0 || x.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH);

      //order list by timestamp
      var sortedDataStructureListH = dataStructureListH.OrderBy(o => o.TimeStampInMs).ToList();

      ////delete zerro datasets
      //sortedDataStructureListH.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs == 0);

      ////delete older datasets
      //sortedDataStructureListH.RemoveAll(x => x.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH);

      // parse all vertical data
      var nrOfLinesProcessed = 0;
      foreach (var datastructure in sortedDataStructureListH)
      {
        ////first check if timestamp is newer than the last processed buffer
        //if (datastructure.TimeStampInMs <= lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH)
        //{
        //  DebugLogging.WriteLine("Height: Skip buffer, timestamp {0} is same or older then last processed buffer {1}", datastructure.TimeStampInMs, lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH);
        //  continue;
        //}

        int nrOfLinesDiff;
        if (firstTimeStampH)
        {
          nrOfLinesDiff = 1;
          firstTimeStampH = false;
        }
        else
        {
          nrOfLinesDiff = (int)((datastructure.TimeStampInMs - lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH) / sampleTime);//how many samples between last fetch and this
          var remainder = (datastructure.TimeStampInMs - lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH) % sampleTime;
          if (remainder == (sampleTime - 1))
          {
            nrOfLinesDiff++;
          }
        }
        if (nrOfLinesDiff > 1)
        {
          DebugLogging.WriteLine("Height: ## Missed {0} Lines", nrOfLinesDiff - 1);
          droppedLinesH += nrOfLinesDiff - 1;
        }

        //process data
        lastRetrievedBufferTimeStampH = datastructure.TimeStampInMs;
        //DebugLogging.WriteLine("--- Height: Process buffer with timestamp {0}", datastructure.TimeStampInMs);
        //store this data
        twH.WriteLine("{0};{1};{2};", datastructure.TimeStampInMs, datastructure.PositionInMs, datastructure.GetDataString());
        scannedLinesH++;
        nrOfLinesProcessed++;
      }
      DebugLogging.WriteLine("Height: Processed {0} Lines", nrOfLinesProcessed);
    }

    if (Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(DateTime.Now, lastStatusUpdateTime) > StatusUpdateTimeInMs)
    {
      //send capture status
      lastStatusUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
      bgw.ReportProgress(-1,
        new StringEventArgs(string.Format("Horizontal: {0}/{1}   Vertical: {2}/{3} [dropped lines/total]",
          droppedLinesW, scannedLinesW, droppedLinesH, scannedLinesH)));
    }
    DebugLogging.WriteLine("ProcessTime={0} ms", Helpers.TimeDiffInMs(DateTime.Now, lastCaptureTime));
  }
  //stop capturing data
  twW.Flush();
  twW.Close();
  twH.Flush();
  twH.Close();
}
```

Normaly fetching data takes around 7 ms, but on timestamp 10:07:04:833, you can see it taked 45 ms. This delay was not in the Backgroundworker Thread.
The logging:

```
10:07:04:766 *** Fetch all buffers
10:07:04:767 RegistersGet(modbusAddress=02, index=600, size=98)
10:07:04:767 ModbusMsg Send: 06 98 00 00 00 06 02 03 02 58 00 62 
10:07:04:769 ModbusMsg Received: 06 98 00 00 00 c6 02 03 00 85 06 b8 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 bd 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c2 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c7 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 cc 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 ae 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 b3 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
10:07:04:770 RegistersGet succedded
10:07:04:770 RegistersGet(modbusAddress=02, index=740, size=70)
10:07:04:770 ModbusMsg Send: 06 99 00 00 00 06 02 03 02 e4 00 46 
10:07:04:772 ModbusMsg Received: 06 99 00 00 00 8e 02 03 00 85 06 b9 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 be 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c3 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c8 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 cd 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 af 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 b4 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
10:07:04:772 RegistersGet succedded
10:07:04:773 *** Fetch all buffers, ready, FetchTime=7; timeDiff=22 ms
10:07:04:773 Width: Processed 5 Lines
10:07:04:774 Height: Processed 4 Lines
10:07:04:776 ProcessTime=3 ms
10:07:04:788 *** Fetch all buffers
10:07:04:788 RegistersGet(modbusAddress=02, index=600, size=98)
10:07:04:789 ModbusMsg Send: 06 9a 00 00 00 06 02 03 02 58 00 62 
10:07:04:810 ModbusMsg Received: 06 9a 00 00 00 c6 02 03 00 85 06 db 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 e0 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c2 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 c7 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 cc 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 d1 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 d6 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
10:07:04:828 RegistersGet succedded
10:07:04:828 RegistersGet(modbusAddress=02, index=740, size=70)
10:07:04:829 ModbusMsg Send: 06 9b 00 00 00 06 02 03 02 e4 00 46 
10:07:04:831 ModbusMsg Received: 06 9b 00 00 00 8e 02 03 00 85 06 ff 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 07 04 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 07 09 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 eb 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 f0 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 f5 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 85 06 fa 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 
10:07:04:833 RegistersGet succedded
10:07:04:833 *** Fetch all buffers, ready, FetchTime=45; timeDiff=60 ms
10:07:04:834 Width: Processed 4 Lines
10:07:04:835 Height: ## Missed 5 Lines
10:07:04:836 Height: Processed 7 Lines
```

Comment: Have you considered using your own thread (NOT a backgroundworker) and playing with the priority? THAT SAID - Windows is not a real time OS and C# is not real time capable. The UDP device is bad because it has no buffering. Have you checked the API there? Alternative use a high precision callback - not a normal background worker.

Comment: I thought of using a Thread instead, but reading on the internet told me that this will not increase the performance. 

I also added       
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
to the backgroundworker, with no performance increase.

The device has buffers, and they are full every 35 ms. 
I tried making more buffers but then I need more time to fetch the data.
7 buffers had the best performance.

Comment: It just takes a gen#2 garbage collection to ruin your "real-time" guarantee.  Not the only source of delays, your BGW thread also has to compete with other threads owned by other processes.  The default thread quantum on the workstation version of Windows is 3 times the interrupt rate. 3 x 15.625 ~= 45 msec.  You can only get ahead with native code that uses timeSetEvent() and a carefully locked-down machine.  Or a device driver.

Answer (score 0):

Having both a responsive user interface and a strict real-time hardware driver (Modbus master) at the same time is hard. The proper, maintainable solution would be to use a non-garbage collected language for writing the hardware driver and glue it to the application with a managed API that is not real-time any more.

If you do not want / cannot make such drastic redesign, try to [reconfigure the garbage collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to match your needs better. Put this in your startup code (static Main method for WinForms, App.OnStartup for WPF):

```
System.Runtime.GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your response.
I was afraid that with the current implementation I was already at the limits of a non-realtime system. If it is not desirable that we drop a few lines, then I will have to redesign the whole system.
Thanks everyone!